# Actualizar mi aplicación sin necesidad de borrarle los datos o desinstalar y volver a instalar la aplicación - Android

Tags: java, android

Estaba trabajando con un ejemplo de un RecyclerView y SQLite, en dicho RecyclerView, La aplicación va muy bien pero al momento de hacer una actualización a mi código nativo en android y generar una nueva apk para actualizar la aplicación anterior, en mi emulador/celular no surten efecto los cambios generados, se queda guardada la información de la primer apk, no cambia textos, o no inserta nuevos elementos.

Ejemplo en mi primer aplicación tengo en mi ReciclerView un texto que dice MIS REPRESENTANTES, hago una actualización y lo cambio por MIS CANDIDATOS, genero una nueva apk e instalo una nueva apk pero no surten efecto dichos cambios, mi ReciclerView sigue mostrando MIS REPRESENTANTES.

**Dichos cambios los edito desde mi clase BaseDatos.java**

**Código java de Actividad principal**

```
package com.herprogramacion.alquileres;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.herprogramacion.alquileres.provider.Contrato.Alquileres;

public class ActividadListaAlquileres extends AppCompatActivity implements     AdaptadorAlquileres.OnItemClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

private RecyclerView listaUI;
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
private AdaptadorAlquileres adaptador;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.actividad_lista_alquileres);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Filtro...", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Acción", null).show();
        }
    });

    // Preparar lista


    listaUI = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.lista);


    listaUI.setHasFixedSize(true);

    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);


    listaUI.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


    adaptador = new AdaptadorAlquileres(this, this);


    listaUI.setAdapter(adaptador);


    // Iniciar loader
   getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(1, null, this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_actividad_lista_alquileres, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(AdaptadorAlquileres.ViewHolder holder, String idAlquiler) {
    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), ":id = " + idAlquiler,
            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new CursorLoader(this, Alquileres.URI_CONTENIDO, null, null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    if (adaptador != null) {
        adaptador.swapCursor(data);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
}
}
```

**Código java de Actividad Adaptador**

```
package com.herprogramacion.alquileres;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;



public class AdaptadorAlquileres extends    RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorAlquileres.ViewHolder> {
private final Context contexto;
private Cursor items;

private OnItemClickListener escucha;

interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onClick(ViewHolder holder, String idAlquiler);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnClickListener {
    // Referencias UI
    public TextView viewNombre;
    public TextView viewUbicacion;
    public TextView viewDescripcion;
    public TextView viewPrecio;
    public ImageView viewFoto;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        viewNombre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
        viewUbicacion = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ubicacion);
        viewDescripcion = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.descripcion);
        viewPrecio = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.precio);
        viewFoto = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.foto);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        escucha.onClick(this, obtenerIdAlquiler(getAdapterPosition()));
    }
}

private String obtenerIdAlquiler(int posicion) {
    if (items != null) {
        if (items.moveToPosition(posicion)) {
            return items.getString(ConsultaAlquileres.ID_ALQUILER);
        }
    }

    return null;
}

public AdaptadorAlquileres(Context contexto, OnItemClickListener escucha) {
    this.contexto = contexto;
    this.escucha = escucha;

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_lista_alquiler, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    items.moveToPosition(position);

    String s;

    // Asignación UI
    s = items.getString(ConsultaAlquileres.NOMBRE);
    holder.viewNombre.setText(s);

    s = items.getString(ConsultaAlquileres.UBICACION);
    holder.viewUbicacion.setText(s);

    s = items.getString(ConsultaAlquileres.DESCRIPCION);
    holder.viewDescripcion.setText(s);

    s = items.getString(ConsultaAlquileres.PRECIO);
    holder.viewPrecio.setText(String.format("%s", s));

    s = items.getString(ConsultaAlquileres.URL);
    Glide.with(contexto).load(s).centerCrop().signature(new StringSignature(UUID.randomUUID().toString())).into(holder.viewFoto);



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (items != null)
        return items.getCount();
    return 0;
}

public void swapCursor(Cursor nuevoCursor) {
    if (nuevoCursor != null) {
        items = nuevoCursor;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

public Cursor getCursor() {
    return items;
}

interface ConsultaAlquileres {
    int ID_ALQUILER = 1;
    int NOMBRE = 2;
    int UBICACION = 3;
    int DESCRIPCION = 4;
    int PRECIO = 5;
    int URL = 6;
}
}
```

**Código java de Base de datos sqlite donde hago los cambios que posteriormente no se generan**

```
package com.herprogramacion.alquileres.provider;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;

import com.herprogramacion.alquileres.provider.Contrato.Alquileres;


public class BaseDatos extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

static final int VERSION = 1;

static final String NOMBRE_BD = "alquileres.db";


interface Tablas {
    String APARTAMENTO = "alquiler";
}

public BaseDatos(Context context) {
    super(context, NOMBRE_BD, null, VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(
            "CREATE TABLE " + Tablas.APARTAMENTO + "("
                    + BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                    + Alquileres.ID_ALQUILER + " TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,"
                    + Alquileres.NOMBRE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                    + Alquileres.UBICACION + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                    + Alquileres.DESCRIPCION + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                    + Alquileres.PRECIO + " REAL NOT NULL,"
                    + Alquileres.URL_IMAGEN + " TEXT NOT NULL)");

    // Registro ejemplo #1
    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put(Alquileres.ID_ALQUILER, Alquileres.generarIdAlquiler());
    valores.put(Alquileres.NOMBRE, "Mis representantes");
    valores.put(Alquileres.UBICACION, "México");
    valores.put(Alquileres.DESCRIPCION, "Conoce a los posibles candidatos a la presidencia de México 2018");
    valores.put(Alquileres.PRECIO, "¿Quiénes son?");
    valores.put(Alquileres.URL_IMAGEN, "http://parkwebstudio.com/images/misrepresentantes.jpg");
    db.insertOrThrow(Tablas.APARTAMENTO, null, valores);

    // Registro ejemplo #2
    valores.put(Alquileres.ID_ALQUILER, Alquileres.generarIdAlquiler());
    valores.put(Alquileres.NOMBRE, "Elecciones");
    valores.put(Alquileres.UBICACION, "México");
    valores.put(Alquileres.DESCRIPCION, "Las elecciones federales de México de 2018, denominadas oficialmente por la autoridad electoral como el Proceso Electoral Federal 2017 — 2018...");
    valores.put(Alquileres.PRECIO, "¡Enterate!");
    valores.put(Alquileres.URL_IMAGEN, "http://parkwebstudio.com/images/elecciones.jpg");
    db.insertOrThrow(Tablas.APARTAMENTO, null, valores);

    // Registro ejemplo #3
    valores.put(Alquileres.ID_ALQUILER, Alquileres.generarIdAlquiler());
    valores.put(Alquileres.NOMBRE, "Reformas y leyes");
    valores.put(Alquileres.UBICACION, "México");
    valores.put(Alquileres.DESCRIPCION, "Enterate de las reformas federales vigentes asi como las proximas a tratar");
    valores.put(Alquileres.PRECIO, "¿En que nos afectan?");
    valores.put(Alquileres.URL_IMAGEN, "http://parkwebstudio.com/images/reformasyleyes.jpg");
    db.insertOrThrow(Tablas.APARTAMENTO, null, valores);

    // Registro ejemplo #4
    valores.put(Alquileres.ID_ALQUILER, Alquileres.generarIdAlquiler());
    valores.put(Alquileres.NOMBRE, "Noticias");
    valores.put(Alquileres.UBICACION, "México");
    valores.put(Alquileres.DESCRIPCION, "Noticias en tiempo real y anuncios clasificados de todo lo relacionado a las elecciones 2018");
    valores.put(Alquileres.PRECIO, "Mantente enterado");
    valores.put(Alquileres.URL_IMAGEN, "http://parkwebstudio.com/images/noticias.jpg");
    db.insertOrThrow(Tablas.APARTAMENTO, null, valores);

    // Registro ejemplo #5
    valores.put(Alquileres.ID_ALQUILER, Alquileres.generarIdAlquiler());
    valores.put(Alquileres.NOMBRE, "Movilízate");
    valores.put(Alquileres.UBICACION, "México");
    valores.put(Alquileres.DESCRIPCION, "Enterate que puedes hacer por tu pais, movilizate!!!");
    valores.put(Alquileres.PRECIO, "¿Por qué?");
    valores.put(Alquileres.URL_IMAGEN, "http://parkwebstudio.com/images/movilizate.jpg");
    db.insertOrThrow(Tablas.APARTAMENTO, null, valores);

    // Registro ejemplo #6
    valores.put(Alquileres.ID_ALQUILER, Alquileres.generarIdAlquiler());
    valores.put(Alquileres.NOMBRE, "¿Porqué participar?");
    valores.put(Alquileres.UBICACION, "México");
    valores.put(Alquileres.DESCRIPCION, "No te preguntes qué puede hacer tu país por ti, pregúntate que puedes hacer tú por tu país");
    valores.put(Alquileres.PRECIO, "¡Animate!");
    valores.put(Alquileres.URL_IMAGEN, "http://parkwebstudio.com/images/porqueparticipar.jpg");
    db.insertOrThrow(Tablas.APARTAMENTO, null, valores);

    // Registro ejemplo #7
    valores.put(Alquileres.ID_ALQUILER, Alquileres.generarIdAlquiler());
    valores.put(Alquileres.NOMBRE, "¿Quiénes somos?");
    valores.put(Alquileres.UBICACION, "México");
    valores.put(Alquileres.DESCRIPCION, "Somos una asociacion civil comprometida con nuestro pais, y el futuro que conlleva un nuevo presidente");
    valores.put(Alquileres.PRECIO, "Conócenos");
    valores.put(Alquileres.URL_IMAGEN, "http://parkwebstudio.com/images/quienessomos.jpg");
    db.insertOrThrow(Tablas.APARTAMENTO, null, valores);

    // Registro ejemplo #8
    valores.put(Alquileres.ID_ALQUILER, Alquileres.generarIdAlquiler());
    valores.put(Alquileres.NOMBRE, "Ubica tu casilla");
    valores.put(Alquileres.UBICACION, "México");
    valores.put(Alquileres.DESCRIPCION, "¿No sabes donde esta tu casilla? Enterate ahora!!!");
    valores.put(Alquileres.PRECIO, "¡Qué no se te pase!");
    valores.put(Alquileres.URL_IMAGEN, "http://parkwebstudio.com/images/ubicatucasilla.jpg");
    db.insertOrThrow(Tablas.APARTAMENTO, null, valores);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    try {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Tablas.APARTAMENTO);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        // Manejo de excepciones
    }
    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

**Código java del contrato con la estructura de la base de datos y forma de las URIs**

```
 package com.herprogramacion.alquileres.provider;

 import android.net.Uri;

 import java.util.UUID;


 public class Contrato {

interface ColumnasAlquiler {
    String ID_ALQUILER = "idAlquiler"; // Pk
    String NOMBRE  = "nombre";
    String UBICACION = "ubicacion";
    String DESCRIPCION = "descripcion";
    String PRECIO = "precio";
    String URL_IMAGEN ="urlImagen";
}


// Autoridad del Content Provider
public final static String AUTORIDAD = "com.herprogramacion.alquileres";

// Uri base
public final static Uri URI_CONTENIDO_BASE = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTORIDAD);


/**
 * Controlador de la tabla "alquiler"
 */
public static class Alquileres implements ColumnasAlquiler {

    public static final Uri URI_CONTENIDO =
            URI_CONTENIDO_BASE.buildUpon().appendPath(RECURSO_ALQUILERES).build();

    public final static String MIME_RECURSO =
            "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd." + AUTORIDAD + "/" + RECURSO_ALQUILERES;

    public final static String MIME_COLECCION =
            "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd." + AUTORIDAD + "/" + RECURSO_ALQUILERES;


    /**
     * Construye una {@link Uri} para el {@link #ID_ALQUILER} solicitado.
     */
    public static Uri construirUriAlquiler(String idApartamento) {
        return URI_CONTENIDO.buildUpon().appendPath(idApartamento).build();
    }

    public static String generarIdAlquiler() {
        return "A-" + UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    public static String obtenerIdAlquiler(Uri uri) {
        return uri.getLastPathSegment();
    }
}

// Recursos
public final static String RECURSO_ALQUILERES = "alquileres";

}
```

**Código java del encapsulador provider, encapsula el acceso a la base de datos**

```
package com.herprogramacion.alquileres.provider;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.herprogramacion.alquileres.provider.BaseDatos.Tablas;
import com.herprogramacion.alquileres.provider.Contrato.Alquileres;



public class ProviderApartamentos extends ContentProvider {

// Comparador de URIs
public static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;

// Casos
public static final int ALQUILERES = 100;
public static final int ALQUILERES_ID = 101;

static {
    uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    uriMatcher.addURI(Contrato.AUTORIDAD, "alquileres", ALQUILERES);
    uriMatcher.addURI(Contrato.AUTORIDAD, "alquileres/*", ALQUILERES_ID);
}

private BaseDatos bd;
private ContentResolver resolver;


@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    bd = new BaseDatos(getContext());
    resolver = getContext().getContentResolver();
    return true;
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case ALQUILERES:
            return Alquileres.MIME_COLECCION;
        case ALQUILERES_ID:
            return Alquileres.MIME_RECURSO;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tipo desconocido: " + uri);
    }
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                    String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    // Obtener base de datos
    SQLiteDatabase db = bd.getWritableDatabase();
    // Comparar Uri
    int match = uriMatcher.match(uri);

    Cursor c;

    switch (match) {
        case ALQUILERES:
            // Consultando todos los registros
            c = db.query(Tablas.APARTAMENTO, projection,
                    selection, selectionArgs,
                    null, null, sortOrder);
            c.setNotificationUri(resolver, Alquileres.URI_CONTENIDO);
            break;
        case ALQUILERES_ID:
            // Consultando un solo registro basado en el Id del Uri
            String idApartamento = Alquileres.obtenerIdAlquiler(uri);
            c = db.query(Tablas.APARTAMENTO, projection,
                    Alquileres.ID_ALQUILER + "=" + "\'" + idApartamento + "\'"
                            + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ?
                            " AND (" + selection + ')' : ""),
                    selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
            c.setNotificationUri(resolver, uri);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("URI no soportada: " + uri);
    }
    return c;
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
                  String[] selectionArgs) {
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: podrías probar cambiando la versión de la base de datos... así se llama a onUpgrade que borra tu tabla y vuelve a llamar a onCreate que la vuelve a generar con los valores que actualizaste.

Comment: como cambio la versión de la base de datos? x.x

Comment: Llegue tarde.. que bueno que ya te ayudaron bien n.n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando actualizas una aplicacion android, la base de datos no se modifica de forma automatica. Para gestionar los cambios en la base de datos cuando actualizas una app, debes cambiar la version de la base de datos y escribir el codigo necesario en el metodo onUpgrade de tu SQLiteOpenHelper.

```
public class BaseDatos extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  static final int VERSION = 2; //Cambia este valor


  ...
}
```

Tu codigo del metodo onUpgrade es correcto segun lo que entiendo necesitas, lo unico que te falto es cambiar el codigo de version de base de datos para que el metodo onUpgrade se ejecute al actualizar la aplicacion.

Comment: Excelente era eso, no estaba actualizando la version de la base de datos, gracias @VorteXavier